# Reinstall GRUB from LiveCD

Tags: linux, grub

I have both windows and linux run on same machine. In Windows, when I set parition C to main boot, I cannot use GRUB anymore. So, I decide to reinstall GRUB.

But, when I use Fedora live CD to boot. I don't see previous Linux parition. I juse see Windows partition. So, I don't know how to mount linux partition to install GRUB.

Here is the output of command:

```
su -c "/sbin/fdisk -l /dev/sd?"

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *          63   188747684    94373811    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2       188747685   976768064   394010190    f  W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda5       251674353   566259119   157292383+   7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda6       566259183   976768064   205254441    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

As you see, maybe sda2 is the linux partition. So, I use this command:

```
mount -t ext4 /dev/sda2 /mnt
```

> mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda2,
>          missing codepage or helper program, or other error
>          In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
>          dmesg | tail or so

I don't know does sda2 is real linux partition or not. (it doesn't appear partition size, so I cannot know). but if this true, I'm pretty sure the partition is format in ext4.

Please help me.

Thanks :)

Comment: What is the output of `sudo blkid /dev/sda*`?

Comment: sda2 is the extended partition. do you have another hard disk installed, i mean /dev/sdb ?

Comment: @LiuYan刘研 no. I doesn't have another disk installed. But when I fist install Linux, linux partition is in LVM Group. Does it matter ?

Comment: @hqt, it doesn't matter. so far I can see is there's no linux partition in your hard disk drive. How did you installed the dual boot? Did you installed linux first, then windows? What did you mean "**when I set parition C to main boot**"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for sure /dev/sda2 is not the parition you want
if you were using LVM i suppose sda5 or sda6 is your physical volume

to list possible physical volumes use

```
lvm lvmdiskscan
```

to scan for logical volumes

```
 lvm lvscan
```

and

```
lvm vgscan -v
```

might be helpful

[here](http://dailypackage.fedorabook.com/index.php?/archives/159-System-Recovery-Week-Using-LVM-In-Rescue-Mode.html) is nice description of recovery process